# session_destroy() after certain amount of time in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently saving a session in my form page:

> $testingvalue = "SESSION TEST";
>
> $_SESSION['testing'] = $testingvalue;

On another page I am calling the session to use the value:

```
<?php
session_start(); // make sure there is a session

echo $_SESSION['testing']; //prints SESSION TEST???
?>
```

Now I want to use the

> session_destroy();

to destroy the session. But what I would like to do is destroy the session after 2 hours have been passed.

Any idea on how to do it and also where should I put it?

I have something like this:

```
 <?php
session_start();

// 2 hours in seconds
$inactive = 7200; 

$session_life = time() - $_session['testing'];

if($session_life > $inactive)
{  
 session_destroy(); 
}

$_session['testing']=time();
    
    echo $_SESSION['testing']; //prints NOTHING?
    ?>
```

Will that work?

If I am inactive for more than 2 hours this should be blank?:

> echo $_SESSION['testing'];

Comment: sessions have something called `timeout`. Use destroy after a logout - or when yu want to destroy the session manually, in other words - when you want to destroy it before the time of its life has passed.

Comment: use session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime);  for your example the lifetime would be 7200 seconds

Comment: What I am looking to do is if the user comes back to the page after 2 hours the session won't keep anything.

Comment: Note $_session !== $_SESSION

Comment: @MikeW Thank you for pointing it out but it's only for example purpose only.

Comment: also the ini setting session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200

Comment: @SiKniB maybe, but the comment `//prints NOTHING?` suggests you didn't know why it printed nothing. Now you do.

Comment: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520237/6521116)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<?php
// 2 hours in seconds
$inactive = 7200; 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $inactive); // set the session max lifetime to 2 hours

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['testing']) && (time() - $_SESSION['testing'] > $inactive)) {
    // last request was more than 2 hours ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for this page
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data
}
$_SESSION['testing'] = time(); // Update session
```

Comment: I added the code and will test and if it works will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Could I include this for example in the __construct function of a Login.php class? or do I put this on every page where session is mandatory?

Comment: Why is ini_set required above?

Answer (score 2):

you need a static start time to expire. `$session_life > $inactive` will always be greater no matter what.

```
session_start();

$testingvalue = "SESSION TEST";
$_SESSION['testing'] = $testingvalue;

// 2 hours in seconds
$inactive = 7200;


$_SESSION['expire'] = time() + $inactive; // static expire


if(time() > $_SESSION['expire'])
{  
$_SESSION['testing'] = '';
 session_unset();
 session_destroy(); 
$_SESSION['testing'] = '2 hours expired'; // test message
}

echo $_SESSION['testing'];
```

or [session-set-cookie-params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)