# Removing an item from the session after 5 minutes Laravel 9

Tags: session, laravel-8

I am working on OTP based authentication system. I want to keep the OTP code in a session variable. and it must forget in 5 min in generating time. is it possible to use session or do need to use cookies?

```
 $otp_code = random_int(10000, 99999);

        session()->get('otp_code');
        session()->forget('otp_code');
        $session = Session::put('otp_code', $otp_code);
```

Comment: You could add another session variablelike Session::put('otp_code_initial_time', time());.. and then validate time when needed

Comment: Please check this link for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179249/session-destroy-after-certain-amount-of-time-in-php